# Rasterize shapefile to raster based on a raster

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I'm wondering if it's possible to rasterize a shapefile based on raster cells as shown below.
I've tried several algorithms on qGIS, but they haven't the option to create a raster based on another raster.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Basically you could vectorize the raster, then select all cells which intersect with the feature you want rasterized and then rasterize the selected cells. One likely problem would be that vectorization doesn't put out single cells, but larger polygons for cells with similar values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The raster represents a DEM, but it is 20000x20000 cells large and I think it would take a lot of time to vectorize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Use SAGA **Profiles from lines** tool (`Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Terraiin Analysis - Profiles`) which returns a layer of points located at every cell center which intersects with your input line. Its attribute table has x, y, z along with distance information.

(2) Rasterize the above point layer using `z` as the cell value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I can't verify if it really works because SAGA algorithms don't work on my computer, despite having tried with 4 different qGIS versions, but I'll consider this solution as valid.